# INSERT into database not working through PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms, sqlite

I have the following code in a php file on my server, and it's supposed to take simple POST input from a HTML form and store it in a database.

```
$var_name = $_POST[post_name];
$var_email = $_POST[post_email];
$var_id = intval($_POST[post_id]);
echo "Name=".$var_name.", email=".$var_email.", id=".$var_id;

$status = $db->query("insert into names (name, email, id) values ('$var_name', '$var_email', $var_id)");
var_dump($status);
```

All of the POST variables are correct, they all store the data I entered into the form, and `db` is definitely set up correctly, as running the following code works as expected, printing out each line in the database:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM names');
while ($name = $results->fetchArray()) 
    echo $name[0]."\n";
```

What happens is, `var_dump($status)` proves that `$status` is false. How can it be false? What am I doing wrong? Inserting the query line into the sqlite3 CLI works perfectly, so I can't see what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: put your query in a variable and var_dump that. $sql = "insert into names (name, email, id) values ('$var_name', '$var_email', $var_id)". use the same variable in the query method. This way you can make sure the query is correct

Comment: What does your database's error report say? If you're using PDO, then you can access it with `var_dump($query->ErrorInfo())`

Comment: Never write such dangerous code. Use prepared statements from day one and never look back: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The query is: << insert into names (name, email, id) values ('a', 'b', 1) >>.. There's nothing wrong with this, but it's still telling me that $status is false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a permissions problem with your database, since the code looks like it should work. Check that you have read/write permissions on the database file.

Also, you should make sure that the folder containing the database file also has read/write permissions as well, because both the folder and the file must be writable in order for an INSERT to work

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have forget some quotes in your code.. begin to try this:

```
$var_name = $_POST['post_name'];
$var_email = $_POST['post_email'];
$var_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
echo "Name=".$var_name.", email=".$var_email.", id=".$var_id;

$status = $db->query("insert into names (name, email, id) values ('$var_name', '$var_email', $var_id)");
var_dump($status);
```